# SQL SSRS updating row based on another row

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a problem which I've searched but I don't think I'm using the correct search keywords. Hoping someone help,

I have a table that looks like this,

```
Name        YEAR
Chicken     2015
Cow         2012
Lion        2014
Lion        **2016**
Tiger       2013
Tiger       2014
Tiger       **2016**
```

Result

```
Name        YEAR
Chicken     2015
Cow         2012
```

I want ALL the corresponding Name set to 'NULL' or preferably lines removed when the YEAR is 2016. So 2 lines of Lion and 3 lines of Tiger are removed because one of them has an YEAR = 2016.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery.  You don't want to see anything to do with names that have a year of 2016, so you just need this logic written into your where clause.

```
SELECT Name, Year
FROM table
WHERE Name not in (
    SELECT Name
    FROM table
    WHERE Year = '2016')
```

For your join situation:

```
SELECT Name, Year
FROM name_table nt
JOIN year_table yt on yt.id = nt.id
WHERE Name not in (
    SELECT Name
    FROM name_table nt
    JOIN year_table yt on yt.id = nt.id
    WHERE Year = '2016')
```

Comment: Doesn't that still just remove the one line with YEAR 2016? I think the issue is my joins preventing this logic from working. I should've mentioned that earlier. The columns above are from 2 different tables, where I have an inner join on an ID

Comment: What all does the table with years have in it?  Is it's just ID and year, with a distinct ID for each row?